# input text color by clicking on parent

Tags: html, css

```js
$('.title').click(function(){
$(this).addClass('titleact');
});
```

```css
.title{
background:#eee;
cursor:pointer;
}

.titleact{
background:lightseagreen;
color:white;
}

.title input{
background:none;
border:none;
outline:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>
<span>abc</span>
<input type='text' value='lorem'>
</div>
```

How to get text color white on input by clicking on `title` using css only?

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
"color:white;"
```

to

```
"color:white !important"
```

Or the better way would be to add

```
".titleact input{ color: white;}"
```

to your css.

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.title').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('titleact');
        $(this).find("*").css("color","#fff");
        });
    </script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.title').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("titleact");
    $(this).find("*").addClass("titleact");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: did you see ` using css only?`

Comment: i saw it but just suggest for more benefit